# Missing index.html in dist/browser after building Angular universal projects by running "npm run build:ssr"

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

After installing Angular universal by running:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

I went to build the project by:

```
npm run build:ssr
```

When I run serve the project with

```
npm run serve:ssr
```

Error appears:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/dist/functions/browser"
    at Function.render (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:55087:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:56954:7)
    at /Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:201044:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:57833:5)
    at next (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:58067:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:58042:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:57833:5)
    at /Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:57368:22
    at param (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:57440:14)
    at param (/Users/syahiruddin/RVI-clone/app/dist/functions/server/main.js:57451:14)
```

Upon checking for days, I have a look in the browser folder and found that it is missing the index.html. Which I think is the cause of the error. Or I could be wrong.

I have no idea how to resolve this, and I have checked my angular.json. Please help as I have been looking to resolve this for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that there is another error that was causing the missing index.html in the browser folder.

```
Error: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 1.00 MB was not met by 418.72 kB with a total of 1.41 MB.
```

To solve this, I increase the budgets for maximumWarning and maximumError to slightly more than the initial.

angular.json

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1.5mb",
                  "maximumError": "1.5mb"
                },
```

With that, it was able to build successfully.